# How soon can i retrieve transactions after a successful addSiteAccount1 call?

Tags: yodlee

Let's say i have successfully added a user using addSiteAccount1. How long do i have to wait in order to begin retrieving the user's transactions using executeUserSearchRequest?
  Is there any other way way to retrieve the transactions other than using executeUserSearchRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it takes around 2-5 seconds.
Yes you can have a look at our Yodlee APIs which was recently out and you can retrieve transactions even from that. Following are the details:

Yodlee API: https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API

For getting Transactions:https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/transactions/getTransactions

Endpoint: GET /{cobrandName}/v1/transactions

API: Get Transactions

Hope that helps.

Regards,

Krithik